# Comparison test $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1 + \ln(k)}{k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \,\frac{1 + \ln(k)}{k}$$

Determine whether it converges or diverges.

I don't think I could do limit comparison test because the $\ln(k)$ messed me up. Pretty sure I could do this with integral test but I think this is possible with comparison test as well. Could someone tell me if it is? For instance I'm looking for a $b_k$ value that is $$0 \leq a_k \leq b_k$$

My textbook uses $b_k = \frac{1}{k}$, but how is the hypothesis met with this? $$\frac{1+\ln(k)}{k} \,\geq\, \frac{1}{k}$$

Thats wrong it should be $a_k \leq b_k$ $\forall n \geq 1$

Comment: The harmonic series diverges and this each terms of this series is greater than that of the harmonic series.

Comment: If you insist of using the inequality $0\leq a_k\leq b_k$, then you should be looking for $a_k$ and not $b_k$. This is the trick if you prove for divergence. So, we can take $a_k=\frac{1}{k}$ and $b_k=\frac{1+\ln k}{k}$ and then apply comparison test for divergence.

Comment: There is a divergence comparison test?

Comment: @user29418 Not for k=1.

Comment: The only definition for comparison test I know is: Assuming all these are series If $0 \leq a_n \leq b_n, \forall n \in \mathbb N$, then $\sum b_n$ converges. Same with diverges.

Comment: I forgot to add ≥*. Correction: 1+ln(k) ≥ 1. Divide both sides by k.

Comment: @user349557 Well, its your turn to look exactly the Comparison Test for Divergence.

Comment: Oh. I may have the definition wrong. My textbook explained it in one sentence and didn't talk about the divergence case. Is this for the divergence case: Assuming $a_k$ and $b_k$ are series. If $0 \leq b_k \leq a_k$ and $\sum a_k$ diverges, then $\sum b_k$ diverges? Because that would make more sense

Comment: The comparison test says that if $0 \le a_n \le b_n$ for every n, and $\sum b_n$ converges, then $\sum a_n$ converges as well. It follows from this (by taking the contrapositive) that if $\sum a_n$ does *not* converge then $\sum b_n$ does *not* converge. Does this make it clearer?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you.

Comment: @Nick The comment given by Dr MV is already enough.

Comment: The derivative of $f(x)=(1+\ln x)/x$ is $f'(x)=(1-\ln x)/x^2$ which is $<0$ for $x\geq 3$. So the sequence $(\;(1+\ln k)/k\;)_k$ is monotonic for $k\geq 3 .$ So you can also use the Cauchy Condensation Test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is correct.  Note that $1+\log(k)\ge 1$ for all $k\ge 1$.  Hence,

$$\frac{1+\log(k)}{k}\ge \frac1k$$

Since the harmonic series diverges, then the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1+\log(k)}{k}$ diverges by comparison.  That is to say, the series of interest dominates the divergence harmonic series.

Comment: Hi Dr. MV. I thought it says by the definition that you have to find a value $b_k$ that is greater than or equal to $a_k$ and both are positive, then we can use $b_k$ to find the result? So im wondering why this is allowed. For example $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{tan^{-1}(n)}{n^{3/2} + sin^2 (n)} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi/2}{n^{3/2}}$$. The textbook does it the exact same way you do it but I don't understand why this is allowed?

Comment: For $0\le a_k \le b_k$, we can show that the series $\sum a_k$ converges by showing that $\sum b_k$ converges.  And the converse is also true.  That is what we used here.  We have $a_k\ge b_k\ge0$ with $\sum b_k$ divergent.

Comment: I got the definition mixed up. Thanks for clearing it up

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark